# Network Monitoring: Is there a way to observe the various IP addresses that send data on servers with proxies?

Tags: elasticsearch, network-monitoring

A noob here. I would like to understand something and also talk about what we did till now about this topic. My teammates and I work on Elastic and monitor a few data from a server for a big xyz company. There has been a recent requirement from the big xyz company to see if there can be a possibility to monitor data traffic from particular IP addresses (they are a smaller company withour a VPN service and they are whitelisted in the big xyz comnpany's servers as well) or better put, say a series of IP addresses that are sending data through an ETL tool we also monitor.

It is more to do with understanding the requirements since the connection we are testing and finally will implement does have a bottleneck with speed and we would like to understand the sizes of data from the region and this will help us say that we did a test phase and with a speed of 1 GBps and data packet of 1TB, we then can limit the days for the project end.

Since we have a firewall and a proxy, we aren't able to see the separate IP addresses rather, just the ones in our region. (Proxy!)

I would like to learn and will gladly edit the question so that everyone can understand.

The kinds of recommendations put before us are:

- Check the POM.XML file (does this file contain what we need?)
- Try the HTTP client since the ETL tool is springboot based
- Try reverse proxy settings
- Leave the company :)

As mentioned before, I dont work with networks and this is an opportunity for me to learn. So, please enlighten me.

We tried to see if the packets we send through the ETL tool show us anything different/ different IP addresses. But, it did not work.